# No output, it says <terminated> on Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, dictionary, printing, output

This is Name class:

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    public String lastName, firstName;
    public Name(String last, String first) {
        lastName = last; firstName = first;
    }

}
```

This is PhoneBook class, the problem is in this class:

```
public class PhoneBook {

    private SortedMap<Name, Integer> directory = new TreeMap<Name, Integer>();

    public PhoneBook(ArrayList<Name> names, ArrayList<Integer> phones) {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            directory.put(names.get(i), phones.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (Map.Entry<Name,Integer> entry : directory.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(entry.getKey());
            System.out.print(entry.getValue());
            System.out.println();
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> phones = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
        PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook(names, phones);
        phones.add(8888);
        phones.add(9999);
        names.add(new Name("Shaun-Williams", "Joe"));
        names.add(new Name("Baltimore", "Paul"));
        pb.print();
    }
```

I don't understand what I did wrong but this doesn't print anything. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does not pass method arguments by reference but rather by value so the value your passing in that constructor is empty hence the not printing when you call the print method.

Initialize your objects first, then pass the build up into the constructor like below.

```
 ArrayList<Integer> phones = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
 phones.add(8888);
 phones.add(9999);
 names.add(new Name("Shaun-Williams", "Joe"));
 names.add(new Name("Baltimore", "Paul"));
 //pass the object after you've done your initializations
 PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook(names, phones);
 pb.print();
```

Hope this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) can help out